# how java script initilised variable prints undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
01  print(x === undefined); // prints "true"
02  var x = 3;
03   
04  //will return a value of undefined
05  var myvar = "my value";
06   
07  (function() {
08    alert(myvar);//undefined       -- here i don't understand ho it print undefined 
09    var myvar = "local value"
10  })();
```

Comment: is it the complete javascript that you posted, because, it seems like partial! and seeing this you cannot tell the scope of anonymous function printing the "myvar" value.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your anonymous function within an anonymous function call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting). When the function executes, `var myvar = "local value"` gets pushed to the top of the function with a value of undefined (overwriting the previously defined `var myvar = "my value";`).

**Edit: added slightly modified example from [Adequately Good](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)**

This means that code like this:

```
function foo() { 
    bar(); 
    var x = 1; 
}
```

is actually interpreted like this:

```
function foo() { 
    var x; 
    bar();
    alert(x); //alerts undefined 
    x = 1; 
}
```

Comment: Why so, and how is it pushed to the top of function?

Comment: I included an example from the link, but seriously, keep reading that article until you understand. There's a lot of really crucial information in there. It's just the way JavaScript gets parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript creates a name for the variable regardless of where it is initialized. It does not actually initialize the variable until after that line of code has run.

```
print(x === undefined); // prints "true"
var x = 3;
print(x === undefined); // prints "false"
```